# How can I add add patches for mule runtime version 3.6.4-HF1 to mule runtime 3.6.4 in maven pom.xml?

Tags: maven, mule

I have two jar files for applying patches to Mule runtime version 3.6.4 to support 3.6.4-HF1. I want to add dependencies for the same ion pom.xml file.

How can I achieve that?
I'm running the below command but it is not working.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile={patch-file-name}.jar -DgroupId=com.mule.support -Dversion=1.0 -DartifactId={patch-name} -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? Your command installs the dependencies in your local repository, but in order to make them available to your project you must properly modify your pom. Could you please add your pom to the question?

Answer (score 0):

There is no 3.6.4-HF1 version for on premis, only for CloudHub. If you select 3.6.4-HF1 you don't need to do anything else. 
If you have a problem in your Standalone Server and think that the fix in 3.6.4-HF1 fixes it, please contact MuleSoft's support team.